# After a MySQL docker compose, SQL script execution doesn't work

Tags: mysql, docker

I want to create a MySQL Docker container which execute automatically 4 SQL script, such that I can found my schema and user already ready to use. In order to do this, I put in my folder my-mysql 4 SQL script files and my docker-compose.yml as following

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my_password
    ports:
    - my-ip_address:my_port
    volumes:
    - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    - ./mysql-init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    command:
    - --max-allowed-packet=64M

volumes:
  mysql: {}
```

I execute it by `sudo docker-compose up`, checking no other MySQL container before this. And the MySQL container creates itself correctly, but the script doesn't execute it and I can't find my database. How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an shell insight you container, so connect to this container like this `docker exec -it mysql bash`, wher "mysql" stands for the container name.

Look insight this container, and check, if your scripts are located at the right place, if the filesystem-rights matches and if you call / trigger those scrips correctly.